# Scroll bar shows up even when I don't want it

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

I am trying to get this scroll bar to appear when I need it and not be there when I don't and so far I can get the scroll bar to appear, but it remains there even when the image proceeds off screen. I know it probably has something to do with the fact that the div above it is going off screen but I have cannot get the scroll bar to disappear when I don't want it on the innerwrapperabout div.

```
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/KendraTemplate.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>kendraRossUtahState</title>
 <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<link href="file:///C|/Users/Mathew Hammett/Desktop/Designs/Dreamweaver/kendraRossUtahState/CSS/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
.MenuDisplay {
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
    background-color:#DDD;
}
.ListItemDisplay {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:2%;
    margin-right:2%;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
</style>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
</head>

<body background="../backgroundImage/UtahMoutains-copy7.png"   style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; background-attachment:fixed; background-size:cover; margin:0px;">

    <div style=" float:left; width:100%; background-color:#DDD; position:relative; margin:0px;">

        <img src="../backgroundImage/utahGovLogo.png" style=" float:left; padding:20px;">

        <img src="../Images/Search%20Button.png" style="float:right; padding:20px;">

    </div>
    <nav style="z-index:9;">
        <ul style="list-style:none; text-align:center; background-color:#DDD; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, Neue,sans-serif; font-size:120%; color:#666; margin:0px;">
            <a href="government.html"><li class="ListItemDisplay" style="cursor:default;">Government 
                <ul class="MenuDisplay">
                    <li><a href="stateagencies.html">State Agencies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="governorsoffice.html">Governors Office</a></li>
                    <li><a href="executivebranch.html">Executive Branch</a></li>
                    <li><a href="legislative.html">Legislative Branch</a></li>
                    <li><a href="judicial.html">Judicial Branch</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cityandcountygovernment.html">City & County Government</a></li>
                    <li><a href="federalgovernment.html">Federal Government</a></li>
                    <li><a href="electionandvoting.html">Election & Voting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="utahcodeandconstitution.html">Utah Code & Constitution</a></li>
                    <li><a href="statetelephonedirectory.html">State Telephone Directory</a></li>
                    <li><a href="utahdata.html">Utah Data</a></li>
                    <li><a href="openutahgov.html">Open.Utah.gov</a></li>
                </ul><!-- end of  Government  drop down menu-->
            </li><!-- end of Government Button-->
            </a>
            <li class="ListItemDisplay" style="cursor:default;">Services
              <ul class="MenuDisplay">
                    <li><a href="onlineservices.html">Utah.gov Online Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="citizenservices.html">Citizen Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="businessservices.html">Business Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="govtogovservices.html">Gov to Gov Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="financial.html">Financial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="legal.html">Legal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="utahregistration.html">Utah.gov Registration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="citizenalerts.html">Citizen Alerts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="trending.html">Trending</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li class="ListItemDisplay" style="cursor:default;">Employment
              <ul class="MenuDisplay">
                    <li><a href="findajob.html">Find a Job</a></li>
                    <li><a href="educationandtraining.html">Education & Training</a></li>
                    <li><a href="stateemployment.html">State Employment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="ListItemDisplay" style="cursor:default;">Business
              <ul style="text-decoration:none; list-style:none; background-color:#DDD;">
                    <li><a href="onlinebusinessservices.html">Online Business Serices</a></li>
                    <li><a href="startingabusiness.html">Starting a Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="runningabusiness.html">Running a Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="relocatingabusiness.html">Relocating a Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dissolvingabusiness.html">Dissolving a Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="assessbusinessidea.html">Assess your Business Idea</a></li>
                    <li><a href="selectbusinessstructure.html">Select your Business Structure</a></li>
                    <li><a href="preparewrittenplan.html">Prepare a Written Business Plan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="govbusinessreq.html">Government Business Requirments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="financialrecources.html">Financial Resources</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="ListItemDisplay" style="cursor:default;">Education
              <ul class="MenuDisplay" style="left:-90px;">
                    <li><a href="k12education.html">K - 12 Education</a></li>
                    <li><a href="collegesanduniversities.html">Colleges & Universities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="educationalrec.html">Educational Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="stem.html">STEM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="historyforkids.html">Utah History for Kids</a></li>
                    <li><a href="homeworkhelp.html">Homework Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="libraries.html">Libraries</a></li>
                    <li><a href="studentnetwork.html">Student Network</a></li>
                    <li><a href="schoolreport.html">School Reports</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="ListItemDisplay" style="cursor:default;">Resident
              <ul class="MenuDisplay" style="left:-230px;">
                    <li><a href="citizensandcom.html">Citizens & Community</a></li>
                    <li><a href="healthandsocial.html">Health & Social Serives</a></li>
                    <li><a href="newcomers.html">Newcomers Guide</a></li>
                    <li><a href="moving.html">Moving to Utah</a></li>
                    <li><a href="carsandtrans.html">Cars & Transportation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="utahlaws.html">Utah Laws</a></li>
                    <li><a href="taxinfo.html">Tax Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="rss.html">RSS ( Just for Youth)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="seniors.html">Seniors.Utah.gov</a></li>
                    <li><a href="neighborhelp.html">Help your Neighbor</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="ListItemDisplay" style="cursor:default;">Visiting
              <ul class="MenuDisplay" style="width:auto; left:-360px;">
                    <li><a href="tavelandtour.html">Travel & Tourism</a></li>
                    <li><a href="stateparks.html">State Parks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="arts.html">Arts & Culture</a></li>
                    <li><a href="highwayinfo.html">Highway Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sportsandrec.html">Sports & Recreation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="artsandleisure.html">Arts & Leisure</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="ListItemDisplay" style="cursor:default;"><a id="aboutbutton" href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ListItemDisplay" style="cursor:default;">Connect
              <ul class="MenuDisplay" style="-webkit-column-count:1; width:150px; left:-90px;">
                    <li><a href="facebook.html">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="twitter.html">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="google.html">Google +</a></li>
                    <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="youtube.html">YouTube</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="EditRegion3" -->

    <div id="mainwrapper">
        <div id="innerwrapperabout">

            <div id="aboutimages">
                <img id="aboutimagepng" src="../Images/executiveGovernment.png" width="627" height="614" alt=""/>
            </div><!-- End aboutimages div-->


        </div><!-- End innerwrapper div-->
    </div><!-- mainwrapper-->


    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
```

CSS:

```
body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:fixed; 
}

nav ul li ul {
display: none;
width:auto;
clear:both;
position:relative;
text-align:left; 
padding:10px;
overflow:auto;
-webkit-column-count:2;
column-count:2;
height:auto;
width:auto;
}

.MenuDisplay{
z-index:9;  
}

.ListItemDisplay{
z-index:9;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
display:block;
position:absolute;
top: 100%;
left:0;
height:auto;
width:auto;
column-count:2;
}

nav ul li {
position: relative;
}

nav ul li ul li {
width:290px;
margin:10px;
}

#aboutimages {
background-color:#066F84;
width:40%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display:block;
padding:25px;
min-width:350px;

}

#innerwrapperabout {
width:100%;
display:block;
position:relative;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
}

#mainwrapper{
height:100%;
width:100%;
display:block;
position:fixed;
}

#aboutimagepng{
width:100%;
height:auto;
min-width:300px;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#MainPar{
display:block;  
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the div that has the #066F84 color attached to it is  coded like  it is because I wanted the divs that had the images and content within it to connect with the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Is [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rf1n1auw/) what you are looking for? I moved the `overflow:auto` from `#MainWrapper` to `body` in your CSS.